# Event when adding a related page to a document

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Apart from LogChange is there a more specific event that gets fired when adding/deleting a related page to a document ?

I want to be able to remove a page from cache when this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the global events defined by the `CMS.DocumentEngine.RelationshipInfo.TYPEINFO.Events` property? For example:

```
public class CustomRelationshipEvents : CMSLoaderAttribute
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        RelationshipInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.After += Insert_After;
    }

    private void Insert_After(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear cache here
    }
}
```

Then add your `CustomRelationshipEvents` attribute to an extension of Kentico's `CMSModuleLoader` class...

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for,

Comment: @RadarBug you can find these exact code samples in the documentation as well.  https://docs.kentico.com/api10  and https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events